# How can I eliminate CakePHP's "SHOW FULL COLUMNS" queries?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I realize that these might not necessarily be a **huge** performance issue, but I'd like to get rid of any unnecessary `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM` queries that Cake generates. I've tried using the Containable behavior, which I thought would stop Cake from looking at any associations that I haven't included in my `find()`, but I still see the `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM` queries in my SQL dump. I have also tried `unbindModel()`, but it has no effect.

I'm not an expert, and don't understand all the intricacies of Cake, so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't it cache it when the debug level is set to 0?

Comment: Yup, looks like Cake only uses these queries for debugging purposes and therefore, it goes away when debug is set to 0. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for hijacking; but WHY does Cake do this?

Comment: I have the same problem, although the debug mode is 0, is there anything else that needs to be set?